# Struggling to get the xspec-maven-plugin-1 to work

Tags: xspec

Maven newbie...

I downloaded XSpec using git clone:

```
git clone https://github.com/xspec/xspec.git
```

I set the appropriate environment variables. XSpec seems to work fine.

For the Maven plugin, I am using: `xspec-maven-plugin-1`

To create a Maven project I opened a (Windows) command window and typed:

```
mvn -B archetype:generate -DgroupId=org.test.waypoints -DartifactId=waypoints -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.4
```

That created a waypoints folder along with several subfolders.

I put an XSpec test (waypoints.xspec) in this folder: `waypoints/src/test/xspec`

I put my XSLT program (waypoints.xsl) in this folder: `waypoints/src/main/xsl`

I opened waypoints/pom.xml and added the plugin element shown below into build/pluginManagement/plugins.

The document at https://github.com/xspec/xspec-maven-plugin-1 says: *Don't forget to add a dependency to your Saxon license*. Question #1: How do I add a dependency to my Saxon license? My Saxon license is in this folder: C:\SAXON\saxon-license

I didn't know how to add that dependency but, nonetheless, I pushed ahead. I opened a command window in the folder containing pom.xml and typed:

```
mvn test
```

That didn't seem to do much. I got this message: `Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date`

Question #2: Should I be running some other Maven command prior to the `test` command?

Question #3: How does Maven know to use the XSpec code?

Question #4: Does the plugin element shown below look correct?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.xspec.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>xspec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
            <artifactId>saxon-ee</artifactId>
            <version>10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.xspec</groupId>
            <artifactId>xspec</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <generateSurefireReport>true</generateSurefireReport>
        <saxonOptions></saxonOptions>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run-xspec</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Q4 answer :

Your plugin definition is good. If it is under `/project/build/plugins`, nothing to add. But if it is under `/project/build/pluginManagement/plugins`, the plugin is only configured, but not declared. You have to declare it under `/project/build/plugins/`.

```xml
<project ...>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <!-- your code you put previously in this thread -->
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.xspec.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>xspec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Once plugin is declared, as it is bind (by the `execution` element) to the `test` phase, when mvn runs this test phase, it executes the `xspec-maven-plugin`.

### Q3 answer :

`xspec-maven-plugin`, in its default configuration, knows that xspec files are under `src/test/xspec`. It looks for all files that match `*.xspec` pattern, and run the xspec suite on each of them.

`xspec-maven-plugin`, thru a dependency mechanism, knows where to get XSpec implementation (you've specified XSpec version in plugin dependencies), and it will get the xspec files from xspec implementation to run the xspec suite on each xspec file found in `src/test/xspec`.

### Q2 answer :

No. `mvn test` is enough. Before running `xspec-maven-plugin`, all plugins bound to phase that are before `test` phase are executed. See [Maven Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#setting-up-your-project-to-use-the-build-lifecycle) for more informations. If your `/project/packaging` is `jar`, then project lifecycle is the one described in previous link.

### Q1 answer :

It depends !

- I wrap my Saxon licence file in a jar file, and I put this jar file in my enterprise artifact repository. So, I have an artifact `my.orga.saxon.license:ee:10.1` that I can add to my plugin dependencies, as you've done for xspec implementation. This allows me to avoid copy the licence file in all projects that use Saxon EE. If you want to do so, see [Maven Install plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) or [Maven deploy plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html)
- You can put your licence file in a place where it will be added to classpath. `src/main/java` or `src/main/resources` is a good place for this. I didn't test it (previous bullet for explanation), but it should work.

### More...

The message you get, `Nothing to compile...` comes from Maven Lifecycle, where there is a `compile` phases, where java classes found under `src/main/java` are compiled. In a following phase, `test-compile`, java test classes located in `src/test/java` are compiled. Probably, I should define a `xspec-compile` goal in my plugin, to compile xspec files located in `src/test/xspec` at `test-compile` phase. Everything is done in a single goal. XSpec files are executed in `test` phase, where java unit test are executed.

If you need an example of a pure-XSL Maven project, with XSpec unit tests, you may have a look at [Matthieu Ricaud XML Utilites Project](https://github.com/mricaud/xml-utilities), it uses `xspec-maven-plugin`, but here with Saxon-HE.

I have no Open Source project that uses XSpec with Saxon-EE, I'm sorry.

Hope this help. If you need more precisions, do not hesitate to ring me by private mail, I'll update this thread.

Christophe

Comment: Outstanding! Thank you @Christophe Marchand!